# AppEngine: Preventing external requests

Tags: google-app-engine

Is there an elegant way to prevent requests from referrers outside the application? Looking at the app.yaml documentation, it doesn't seem like this is a in-box functionality but it seems like it'd be so preferred/common that it has to be hidden *somewhere* rather than necessarily having to reimplement it manually for every application.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "requests from referrers outside the application"? E.g. is this a CORS concern?

Comment: Are you using any framework, like Flask or Django?  If so, you can easily intercept every request with a check, like:

`@login_manager.request_loader
@login_manager.header_loader
@login_manager.user_loader`

Comment: @gaefan I'm sure I can, but I was just wondering if it was built-in somewhere as a blanket layer of security.

Comment: Sounds like you are looking for something like hotlinking protection? Referrers can easily be spoofed or even stripped so why bother?

Comment: It's just a type of deterrent for a certain class of abuses that originate from an HTTP client (e.g. unauthorized API/form access, image hotlinking, etc..).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. There is no built-in logic in GAE for that. Any support would have to exist at the level of your application-specific request routing.

Answer (score 0):

It is built in.

In app.yaml you can specify `login: admin` for a handler and it would accept requests just from admin or from AppEngine (*e.g. cron, taskqueues, and pribably urlfetch of the app itself - the last one not 100% sure*).

See docs: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appref#handlers_element

Also you can check HTTP_HEADERS like referer, IP, user agent.

Also you can issue a token and pass/check it with every request.

Comment: I'm talking about general security, not login. I indicated in the original question that the documentation that you provided doesn't have any of this information. Yes, you can set headers so that browsers can enforce CORS. However, I'm hoping for the ability to enforce controlled API access via explicit application-only access (implemented internally by Google) or, at least, stating that only referrers that match the hosting domain (maybe just a string match set in configuration) can do the request. It'd just be one extra layer to protect against some simple attack vectors.

Answer (score 0):

There are probably a few issues being conflated here.

CORS - a browser enforced security measure to prevent pages maliciously or otherwise sending data to non-origin servers. Servers cannot enforce this, only permit it. Permitting this is an application level concern (i.e. Not built in to GAE)

XSRF - a server enforced security measure to stop authenticated users having their account abused by malicious client code. This is an application level concern (i.e. Not built in to GAE)

Authentication - identifying a user or client by some set of permissions. There is some support for this with GAE (cloud endpoints, provided identity service, requiring admin login), but it typically would also be an application level concern. In the case of authorizing a client (as opposed to a user) there is no built in support.

Authorization - different sets of access based on roles/permissions. Not built in.

Other solutions:

Using Host or Origin header - trivially outfoxed by someone implementing a curl request, or any application more sophisticated

API token - fine for server to server over https but trivially compromised when used on a published client (like a web page)

Your best bet is to leverage your framework and have user accounts.

If you don't want to do this, something like XSRF (token in a header and cookie) would be enough in the general case to ensure that a web client was responding to your 'app'. This only works if the client is a web browser though, same as origin/host.

Comment: Yep. I'm looking for a referrer (ergo, header) based solution. As mentioned, I'm just looking for that "one extra layer to protect against some simple attack vectors". It doesn't sound like there's anything for that built-into GAE, though, due to the lack of hard responses on it.

Comment: There is nothing built in because this doesn't actually offer any security. Doing nothing except relying on CORS is ultimately going to be equally as effective (as in circumventing either is the same amount of effort)